# Obter nome das propriedades de um Json

Tags: javascript, json, java

Como faço para obter os nomes das propriedades de um Json utilizando a biblioteca [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)?

**Exemplo de entrada:**

```
{
   "Ficha":[
      {
         "nome":"nome",
         "sobrenome":"sobrenome",
         "idade":"idade",
         "endereco":"endereco",
         "empresa":"empresa",
         "telefones":[
            {
               "residencial":"residencial"
            },
            {
               "celular":"celular"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**Saída esperada:**

```
["nome", "sobrenome", "idade", "endereco", "empresa", "telefones", ...
```

Comment: olha escrevi errado tem que imprimir assim ["nome","sobrenome","idade"]....   os nomes da propriedades

Comment: Você fala na biblioteca `gson`, então a linguagem é Java, e não JavaScript, correto? Se for o caso, favor remover o tag `javascript` da pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando o [`Gson`](https://github.com/google/gson), você pode usar o método `entrySet` para obter todas as propriedades de um `JsonObject`, como mostra o exemplo abaixo.

```
String json =
    "{" +
        "\"Ficha\":[" +
            "{" +
                "\"nome\":\"nome\"," +
                "\"sobrenome\":\"sobrenome\"," +
                "\"idade\":\"idade\"," +
                "\"endereco\":\"endereco\"," +
                "\"empresa\":\"empresa\"," +
                "\"telefones\":[" +
                    "{" +
                        "\"residencial\":\"residencial\"" +
                    "}," +
                    "{" +
                        "\"celular\":\"celular\"" +
                    "}" +
                "]" +
            "}" +
        "]" +
    "}";
JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject primeiraFicha = json.get("Ficha").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> properties = primeiraFicha.entrySet();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("[");
boolean first = true;
for (Entry<String, JsonElement> property : properties) {
    if (!first) sb.append(",");
    first = false;
    sb.append(property.getKey());
}
sb.append("]");
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: carlosfigueira poderia me mandar as importação esta dando erro

Comment: Você precisa `import` o JsonElement, JsonObject e JsonParser de com.google.gson além de `java.util.Map.Entry` e `java.util.Set`

Comment: vc mexe tambem com fasterXML

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma das forma de fazer oque você procura:

```js
var json = {
  "Ficha": [{
    "nome": "nome",
    "sobrenome": "sobrenome",
    "idade": "idade",
    "endereco": "endereco",
    "empresa": "empresa",
    "telefones": [{
      "residencial": "residencial"
    }, {
      "celular": "celular"
    }]
  }]
};

var output = [];

for (property in json.Ficha[0]) {
  output.push(property);
  // Uma propriedade de cada vez
  alert(property);
}

// Caso deseje utilizar todas as propriedades de uma única vez
alert(output.join(' | '));
```